# Fastest way to populate a matrix with a function on pairs of elements in two numpy vectors?

Tags: python, performance, numpy, pandas

I have two 1 dimensional numpy vectors `va` and `vb` which are being used to populate a matrix by passing all pair combinations to a function.

```
na = len(va)
nb = len(vb)
D = np.zeros((na, nb))
for i in range(na):
    for j in range(nb):
        D[i, j] = foo(va[i], vb[j])
```

As it stands, this piece of code takes a very long time to run due to the fact that va and vb are relatively large (4626 and 737). However I am hoping this can be improved due to the fact that a similiar procedure is performed using the `cdist` method from scipy with very good performance.

```
D = cdist(va, vb, metric)
```

I am obviously aware that scipy has the benefit of running this piece of code in C rather than in python - but I'm hoping there is some numpy function im unaware of that can execute this quickly.

Comment: Use vectorized functions which will process all elements of va and vb at once using Numpy's `outer` functions... Or passing a meshgrid of va and vb ...

Comment: Problem is that this function is custom and changing to be vectorized is non trivial. I tried using `np.meshgrid` and then using `np.vectorize` but the performance improvements were minimal.

Comment: `vectorize` does not do anything to the internals of your `foo`.  It's just a wrapper than ends up calling `foo(a,b)` with each pair of scalars.  It's a convenience, not a speedup tool.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One of the least known numpy functions for what the docs call [functional programming routines](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.functional.html) is [`np.frompyfunc`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.frompyfunc.html). This creates a numpy ufunc from a Python function. Not some other object that closely simulates a numpy ufunc, but a proper ufunc with all its bells and whistles. While the behavior is in many aspects very similar to `np.vectorize`, it has some distinct advantages, that hopefully the following code should highlight:

```
In [2]: def f(a, b):
   ...:     return a + b
   ...:

In [3]: f_vec = np.vectorize(f)

In [4]: f_ufunc = np.frompyfunc(f, 2, 1)  # 2 inputs, 1 output

In [5]: a = np.random.rand(1000)

In [6]: b = np.random.rand(2000)

In [7]: %timeit np.add.outer(a, b)  # a baseline for comparison
100 loops, best of 3: 9.89 ms per loop

In [8]: %timeit f_vec(a[:, None], b)  # 50x slower than np.add
1 loops, best of 3: 488 ms per loop

In [9]: %timeit f_ufunc(a[:, None], b)  # ~20% faster than np.vectorize...
1 loops, best of 3: 425 ms per loop

In [10]: %timeit f_ufunc.outer(a, b)  # ...and you get to use ufunc methods
1 loops, best of 3: 427 ms per loop
```

So while it is still clearly inferior to a properly vectorized implementation, it is a little faster (the looping is in C, but you still have the Python function call overhead).

Answer (score 3):

`cdist` is fast because it is written in highly-optimized C code (as you already pointed out), *and* it only supports a small predefined set of `metric`s.

Since you want to apply the operation generically, to any given `foo` function, you have no choice but to call that function `na`-times-`nb` times. That part is not likely to be further optimizable.

What's left to optimize are the loops and the indexing. Some suggestions to try out:

1. Use `xrange` instead of `range` (if in python2.x. in python3, range is already a generator-like)
2. Use `enumerate`, instead of range + explicitly indexing
3. Use a python speed "magic", such as `cython` or `numba`, to speed up the looping process.

If you can make further assumptions about `foo`, it might be possible to speed it up further.

Answer (score 3):

Like @shx2 said, it all depends on what is `foo`. If  you can express it in terms of numpy ufuncs, then use `outer` method:

```
In [11]: N = 400

In [12]: B = np.empty((N, N))

In [13]: x = np.random.random(N)

In [14]: y = np.random.random(N)

In [15]: %%timeit
for i in range(N):
   for j in range(N):
     B[i, j] = x[i] - y[j]
   ....: 
10 loops, best of 3: 87.2 ms per loop

In [16]: %timeit A = np.subtract.outer(x, y)   # <--- np.subtract is a ufunc
1000 loops, best of 3: 294 µs per loop
```

Otherwise you can push the looping down to cython level. Continuing a trivial example above:

```
In [45]: %%cython
cimport cython
@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)
def foo(double[::1] x, double[::1] y, double[:, ::1] out):
    cdef int i, j
    for i in xrange(x.shape[0]):
        for j in xrange(y.shape[0]):
            out[i, j] = x[i] - y[j]
   ....: 

In [46]: foo(x, y, B)

In [47]: np.allclose(B, np.subtract.outer(x, y))
Out[47]: True

In [48]: %timeit foo(x, y, B)
10000 loops, best of 3: 149 µs per loop
```

The cython example is deliberately made overly simplistic: in reality you might want to add some shape/stride checks, allocate the memory within your function etc.

Comment: Well I have two cases of this code being run. One is calculating the jaccard distance between two vectors. I am aware scipy has a function for this but the behaviour is slightly different in our case. The other is performing a lookup in the dictionary `D[i, j] = a.get((va[i], vb[j]), 1.0)`

Comment: Well, it depends and needs to be measured for your particular setup -- for which `%timeit` is your friend. If you get stuck somewhere en route, best ask a separate question with details. Good luck!